# Send Parse Push Notification from website

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

As the title says, I want to send a push-notification to my android phone via a form on my website. I've googled but didn't found the right answer to my question.
Maybe someone can give me an idea to do that or what I need for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Parse javascript(JS) API to trigger the push notification from cloud. In other words, you can write a cloud function that queries the Installation table and sends push notification. This cloud can be triggered via Parse JS API. Another way, you can use third party of Parse API extension like Parse4j. You can implement your web site server side in java and via Parse4j you can trigger cloud function when the form is submitted and controlled. Hope this helps.

Regards.